# How do I set the accessibilityLabel or accessibilityIdentifier in XCode 5 Interface Builder?

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, xcode5, accessibility

I would like to do this for testing purposes. A lot of predefined Calabash steps rely on identifying on-screen elements with such identifiers. I don't really want to pollute my code by having accessibilityLabel assignments if I could help it!

Answer (score 2):

Click on the UIImageView in Storyboard -> Identity Inspector (on the right panel) -> Accessibility section -> Label.